# Trying to send parameters from a simple Python function to C++

Tags: c++, python

I'm trying to link a `Python` script with a `C++` script. I found this and works.

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    public:
        void bar(){
            std::cout << "Test!" << std::endl;
        }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(); }
}
```

**fooWrapper.py**

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)


f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

To compile I use:

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

If `-soname` doesn't work, use `-install_name`:

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-install_name,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

And to execute just:
`python fooWrapper.py`

This works, it prints me that 'Test!' of the `bar()` function.
The thing is that now I want to send some parameters from the `Python` function to the `C++` function but what I've tried doesnt work.

This is my try:

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    public:
        void bar(int number){
            printf("Number is: %d", number);
            std::cout << "Test!" << std::endl;
        }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(int number); }
}
```

**fooWrapper.py**

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)

num = 5    
f = Foo()
f.bar(num)
```

I get this error. Trying to compile the `C++` function:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘void Foo_bar(Foo*)’:
foo.cpp:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(int number); }
```

seems pretty wrong. `int number` would be a variable decleration, but you want to give a variable as a parameter to a method. For this purpose, it needs to be in the method definition of `Foo_bar`.

Try:

```
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo, int number){ foo->bar(number); }
```

and in your Python code

```
def bar(self, number):
    lib.Foo_bar(self.obj, number)
```